# Why can't I run python code from my command prompt?

Tags: python, command-prompt

```
import : The term 'import' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ import
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (import:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to run the Python interpreter first.

Type "python" and hit Enter.